# Passing a Java socket from thread A to B

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, executor

In a server, there is a thread A listening for incoming connections, typically looping forever. When a connection is accepted, thread A creates a task (say, class `Callable` in Java) and submits it to an `Executor`.
All this really means is that A lost the reference to the socket, and that now there’s a thread B (created by the Executor) that manages the socket. If B experiences any exception, it would close the socket, and there is no risk that the socket, as an operating system resource, will not be reclaimed.

This is all fine if thread B starts. But what if the executor was shut down before B had a chance to get scheduled?

Does anyone think this is an issue? If the reference to the socket is lost due to this, would the garbage collector close the socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like an issue.

The OS will probably eventually free up the socket (at least if it's TCP, as far as I can tell) but it will probably take a relatively long time.

I don't think the garbage collector plays a role in this case. At least not for threads, which after having been started will usually keep running even if there is no reference to them in the code (this is true at least for non-daemon threads). Sockets may behave in a similar manner.

If you cannot guarantee the connection is going to be processed (by starting the handling `Thread` instance as soon as it is established) then you should keep a reference to the socket and make sure you close all of them as soon as possible, which probably means right after `Executor.shutdown()` or similar method has been called.

Please note that depending on how you ask the Executor to shut down it will either process or not threads which already have been submitted to execution but haven't yet started. So be sure to make your code behave accordingly.

Also if you have limited resources (available threads) to process incoming socket connections and don't want them to grow too much, consider closing them immediately after having been accepted so they don't pile up in the unprocessed wait queue, if this is feasible in your project. The client can then retry connecting at a later time. If you still need to consume connections as soon as they come in, consider a non-blocking I/O approach, which will tend to scale better (and up to a point).

Comment: I’m glad I’m not the only paranoid around. My existing code does exactly that. Thread A keeps a reference, and waits until thread B signals that it’s ok to release the reference. If B didn’t take the socket fast enough, then A closes the socket and kills B

Answer (score 2):

> If the reference to the socket is lost due to this, would the garbage collector close the socket?

Probably. But the garbage collector may not run until literally the end of next week: You can't rely on the GC running, pretty much ever, just because 'hey, java has a garbage collector'. It does, and it won't kick in until needed. It may simply never be needed.

Depending on the GC to close resources is a fine way to get your VM killed by the OS for using up too many system resources.

The real question is: What is the causal process that results in shutting down the executor?

If there is some sort of 'cancel all open connections' button, and you implemented that as a one-liner: `queue.shutdown()`, then, no - that is not a good idea: You'll now be leaning on the GC to clean up those sockets which is bad.

I assume your callables look like:

```
Socket socket = ....; // obtained from queue
Callable<Void> socketHandler = () -> {
    try {
       // all actual handling code is here.
    } finally {
        socket.close();
    }
    return null;
};
```

then yeah that is a problem: If the callable is never even started, that `finally` block won't run. (If you don't have `finally` you have an even bigger problem - that socket won't get cleaned up if an exception occurs during the handling of it!).

One way out is to have a list of sockets, abstract away the queue itself, and have that abstraction have a shutdown method which *both* shuts down the queue *and* closes every socket, guarding every step (both the queue shutdown as well as all the socket.close commands) with a try/catch block to ensure that a single exception in one of these steps won't just stop the shutdown process on the spot.

Note that a bunch of handlers are likely to still be chugging away, so closing the socket 'out from under them' like this will cause exceptions in the handlers. If you don't want that, shut down the queue, then await termination (guarded with try/catch stuff), and *then* close all the sockets.

You can close a closed socket, that is a noop, no need to check first and no need to worry about the impact of closing a ton of already-closed sockets.

But do worry about keeping an obj ref to an infinitely growing list of sockets. Once a socket is completely done with, get rid of it - also from this curated list of 'stuff you need to close if the queue is terminated'.

Of course, if the only process that leads to early queue termination is because you want to shut down the VM, don't worry about it. The sockets go away with the VM. In fact, no need to shutdown the queue. If you intend to end the VM, just.. end it. immediately: `System.shutdown(0)` is what you want. There is no such thing as 'but.. I should ask all the things to shut down nicely!'. That IS how you ask. Systems that need to  clean up resources are mostly badly designed (design them so that they don't need cleanup on VM shutdown. All the resources work that way, for example), and if you must, register a shutdown hook.

Comment: _"Systems that need to clean up resources are mostly badly designed."_ I had to add an `acceptor.setReuseAddress(true);` to an Apache MINA-based server I worked on recently so one server process starting right after the other one ended wouldn't throw an _"Address already in use"_ exception when trying to reserve the same server port as before. If I understand you correctly, I'm not sure how that goes along with your statement. Perhaps I missed to add some finalization code to it. But I think doing that still counts as _"I should ask all the things to shut down nicely!"_

Comment: Take a `j.i.Socket` instance, or perhaps a `FileOutputStream` that you're writing to. If you shut down a VM (using CTRL+C or `System.shutdown()`), then the VM will 'nicely' return these things to the OS. You will _not_  get your FOS flushed (which for FOS is irrelevant, but if that was wrapped by a bufferedoutputstream could be a thing), but, then, the VM got CTRL+Ced midway through writing a file. Of course it's incomplete: The user asked for this. If you think that's not okay, the only option is to ignore that CTRL+C entirely, which is weirder. Point is, the file is not 'stuck open forever'.

Comment: @Piovezan it sounds like your apache MINA based server broke this rule and somehow managed to keep a resource 'locked' in a way that a VM shutdown didn't 'unlock' it. That's bad design, but it is possible this wasn't apache's fault. Part of the reason a socket 'cleans up nicely' on CTRL+C is because the OS is also responsible for this. The socket belongs to a process. Process dies? OS knows to clean it up. Bad design: ExFAT file system. Good design: HFS+, btrfs, ext3, etc: Stuff with journals.

Comment: @rzwitserloot - thanks for the detailed answer. I assume that you propose a queue of sockets because you want thread A to just put the socket in the queue and resume listening ASAP. In my code, I have A wait (say 10ms) for thread B to signal. No queue. It’s true that if A waits, then it doesn’t listen, which affects availability. But it also makes sense to slow down the creation of new connections if new threads can’t keep up with them. What do you think?

Comment: @rzwitserloot I see. I misunderstood you as if saying that cleaning up resources after you use them should not be done since the system does that anyway and not being able to do that is bad system design. Naturally system resources should be freed up as soon as you no longer need them. In the case of managed memory you can count on the garbage collector only up to a point and this not always maps to the related system resources. Regarding my server I just checked it, closing all the still open managed sessions at the server side did the trick without relying on `setReuseAddress(true)`. :)

Comment: @claude the socketserver object is still open and running; it is like a little queue on its own, and `.accept()` will pop the top connection off the queue (and wait around for a connection if none are currently 'in line'). Waiting for thread B to get going first is therefore no problem at all. Sounds like a fine way forward :)

Comment: @rzwitserloot It is a bit weird though that synchronously closing all the client-side connections until their end on both sides doesn't work the same way. Perhaps I misunderstand the MINA framework people as invariably suggesting the `setReuseAddress(true)` approach: http://apache-mina.10907.n7.nabble.com/Address-already-in-use-when-restarting-server-td51492.html